# Serializable Class

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

How I can make **Student** class serializable? I'm reading this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document) but I do not know what is the right approach if I would implement it in the below scenario.

```
public class Student
{
    private string _studentNumber;
    private string _lastName;
    private string _firtName;
    private List<Subject> _subjects;

    public Student() { }

    public string StudentNumber
    {
        get { return _studentNumber; }
        set { _studentNumber = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { _lastName = value; }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firtName; }
        set { _firtName = value; }
    }

    public List<Subject> Subjects
    {
        get { return _subjects; }
        set { _subjects = value; }
    }
}

public class Subject
{
    private string _subjectCode;
    private string _subjectName;

    public Subject() { }

    public string SubjectCode
    {
        get { return _subjectCode; }
        set { _subjectCode = value; }
    }

    public string SubjectName
    {
        get { return _subjectName; }
        set { _subjectName = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: serializable **by which serializer** ?

Comment: Also, if you are using the C# 3 compiler, but targeting .NET 2.0, you can use automatically implemented properties, saving some typing - **but** note: that is a breaking change for `BinaryFormatter` (old data will not be compatible if you change to automatically implemented properties)

Comment: sorry, not quite familiar to this but I'm refering to this article. Seems the same with my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `BinaryFormatter`, just add `[Serializable]` before the `public class ....`

For `XmlSerializer`, nothing; that should work fine assuming you want elements

For `DataContractSerializer` (a 3.0 class, strictly speaking), add `[DataContract]` to the class, and `[DataMember]` to the properties

For protobuf-net, you can use the `DataContractSerializer` attributes as long as each `[DataMember]` specifies a unique `Order=`, or you can use `[ProtoContract]` on the class, and `[ProtoMember(n)]` on each property, for unique `n`.

For `JavaScriptSerializer` (technically 3.5), nothing - it should work

For `Json.NET`, nothing - it should work

Other options would include implementing `ISerializable` or `IXmlSerializable`, but frankly: you don't need that.

Comment: @yonan2236 heh; however, it emphasises an important point: there are multiple serializers available, and each of them have different rules and formats

Comment: Ok, I will try again. I'll get back to you Sir.

Answer (score 2):

Usually i serialize to make a deep copy of my object without implementing `IClonenable` interface.

In your case you can use

```
[Serializable()]
public class Student
{
   // Your Class
}
```

make a extension method

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{  
    public static T DeepClone<T>(this T element)
    { 
        MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        b.Serialize(m, element);
        m.Position = 0;
        return (T)b.Deserialize(m);
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
yourclassobject.DeepClone();
```